# select drop down is expanding long in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am populating values in to select drop down using ajax call dynamically.
My code is working fine in IE8 but not in IE9. select dropdown is not appearing properly. It is exapading.

Here my snippet code:

```
if(xmlHttpReq.status==200)
{
    var acaComplRulesDtls=xmlHttpReq.responseText;
    //resetting individualstoApplyComplianceRules  dropdown as blank
    document.getElementById("individualstoApplyComplianceRules").innerHTML="";
    var spiltedACACompRules=acaComplRulesDtls.split("###");
    if(spiltedACACompRules.length==2){
        var indvNames=spiltedACACompRules[0];
        var indvNumbers=spiltedACACompRules[1];
        var spiltedIndvNames=indvNames.split("~~");
        var spiltedindvNumbers=indvNumbers.split("^^");
        var namelen=spiltedIndvNames.length;
        var numberlen=spiltedindvNumbers.length;
        //checking names & numbers length same or not
        if(namelen==numberlen){
            var selectField=document.getElementById("individualstoApplyComplianceRules");
            for(var i=0; i<namelen-1; i++){
                var optionField = document.createElement("OPTION");
                optionField.text = spiltedIndvNames[i];
                optionField.value = spiltedindvNumbers[i]
                selectField.options.add(optionField);
            } //for loop ends here
        }
    } //if
```

Can any one help me to resolve this browser compatibility issue?

Thanks in advance..

[screen shot http://imageshack.com/a/img811/177/bgzy.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img811/177/bgzy.png)

Comment: I don't see any screentshot here! does anyone sees that??

Comment: I couldn't able to attach screenshot... When I am trying to attach, validation message "you need 10 reputations to attach image" has been shown.

Comment: Then use a free image uploading site to upload the screenshot (like Imageshack, Photobucket etc) and link the result.

Comment: I linked the image. please Click on "Click to see the screen shot image here" link to see the image.

Comment: I found too many white spaces in response text. If I set hard coded values in to dropdown dynamically with out using ajax, it is working fine. I mean no dropdown issue.

Comment: Hi guys,
I found solution. My issue is resolved. 
ajax response text contains many white spaces.

I removed whitespaces using replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'') java script method.
now select dropdown is appearing fine.

thanks to all !!! 
have a great day!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. My issue is resolved. 
ajax response text contains many white spaces.

I removed whitespaces using replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'') java script method.
now select dropdown is appearing fine.

thanks to all !!! 
have a great day!!!